# Programs not Upgraded?

Tags: apt, source-packages

This question has been asked before, I know, but I think my situation is a little... odd.

I've been trying to `install build-essential` so I can do some development, but I keep getting a huge long dependencies list that I can't install manually.

I've tried multiple guides to this, including the `dpkg -i` trick before realizing that was for `.deb` packages only (unless I totally misunderstood that entire Q & A).  I've tried installing through Synaptic and manually through the mirror sites, I've tried adding lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` like some have suggested but so far nothing has happened.

This isn't so much a question of how to fix this, but more of a what's going on? I've run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` with no change. I've then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. The output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` is:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages have been kept back:
      cpp-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasan0 libatomic1
      libgcc-4.8-dev libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6     libstdc++6:i386
      libtsan0
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

The output of `sudo apt-get update` is just the usual `Hit http://...` and `Ign http://...`. However, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` has changed it until I try to do any other update, upgrade or install. It's output is this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages have been kept back:
      cpp-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasan0
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

When downloading build-essential through Synaptic, it had wanted to get rid of this program anyway, so I decided I'd just use `remove` or `purge` to get rid of them. However, they have dependencies to get rid of them (which makes zero sense)? I'll show you what I got.

```
    $ sudo apt-get purge gcc-4.8-base
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     gir1.2-dee-1.0 : Depends: libdee-1.0-4 (>= 1.2.7+13.10.20130924.1) but it is not going to be installed
     system-image-dbus : Depends: system-image-common (= 2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Although, in a totally unrelated and entirely similar issue I had, I discovered that removing these packages actually cause Ubuntu to stop working altogether! So now I don't know why these packages won't update or are being "held back" like the `dist-upgrade` command tells me. Sorry for the long question. I hope I got the main points across clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by actually breaking Ubuntu.

While trying to install `build-essential` I tried removing these packages that were "held back" and Ubuntu actually broke. I could only load Ubuntu through recovery mode and, after lots of playing with a terminal, I managed to fix Ubuntu enough to boot to a terminal only version of Ubuntu. I had managed to uninstall the Ubuntu Desktop itself (as well as some other very important files that make computers work and stuff).

While trouble-shooting *this* problem I discovered an argument that for some reason has only ever fixed similar problems for me with the Desktop and the `build-essential` package. I got a huge long dependency for the Desktop because very important files were missing and I couldn't unlock root for some odd reason to save my files which I needed for school. I instead just researched this new problem and discovered that if I use `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall` then it would install all dependencies with it (why hasn't anyone used this before!!?). I then tried that with `ubuntu-desktop` and it install just fine and now I have both things. So I guess what was happening is that I had just messed up some resource list so that files that needed to be updated just weren't getting updated.

In short and answer to both questions, what was happening was this: I made a mistake in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` that prevented certain important files to update and to install `build-essential` you just have to add `checkinstall` to the end of your `apt-get` command. If you have this same problem at any point in your life, you might consider moving your important documents to a computer you won't regularly break.